# ESP 01 lost its firmware when it disconnected

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

[image]

Hi I am using Arduino uno & ESP-01

ESP-01 is working well when I put firmware to ESP, for example, wifi spreading or AT command is okay.

but when I disconnect arduino from PC(disconnect USB connection)

ESP-01 suddenly do not work anything. no spread wifi, no AT command reaction..

so I always have to re-input the firmware to ESP again, for make it work again.

How can I make maintain ESP-01 's firmware?

picture is my connection status. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have io 0 puled LOW so the esp-01 firmware starts in flashing mode and the firmware starts immediately after flashing (no reset).

Remove io 0 to ground connection and add a pull-up for io 0 over a 10kOhm resistor if you want the esp-01 to start normally.

Note: powering the esp-01 from the 3.3 V pin of Uno (150mA max) could be insufficient for esp8266 WiFi operations at top transmit power (according to specs it can draw to 170 mA).